# Rewrite custom URL parameters in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

I have added parameter to WordPress URL for filtering page content.

Current URL:

```
http://localhost/wp/profiles?skills=XYZ
```

And I want to rewrite like this:

```
http://localhost/wp/profiles/skills/XYZ
```

After doing some search, I get to know that I can achieve those results with the help of `add_rewrite_rule` and I tried several solutions from Stack Overflow. But none of them worked for me.

Tried this piece of code:

```
add_action('init', 'profiles_permalinks');

function profiles_permalinks(){
add_rewrite_rule(
        '^profiles/([^/]*)$',
        'index.php?pagename=profiles&skills=$matches[1]',
        'top'
        );
}
```

I am very new to these URL rewrites, so I am unable to figure that out.

Comment: check out this may be this can be work https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-permalinks-url-rewriting/

Comment: thanks for the resource, I've tried something similar but it doesn't work. You can check sample code in question.

Comment: may be checked out this https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/create-custom-wordpress-rewrite-rules-pretty-permalinks/ may be changed in .htaccess file help slove this